# Topology : Comeager Set in Open Set - Comeager upwards?

Tags: general-topology

Assume X has a topology $\tau _X$ of open subsets of X (call an open set U,V).

Assume there is a comeager subset of V (call it C) in the topology $\tau _V$ created from an open set V, which is a subset of an open set U.

**Question** : Will C be a comeager set in the topology $\tau _U$ created from the open set U ? Similarly would C be a comeager set in X ? If it isn't, is there an example where it is not true?

Many Thanks

Comment: Your second paragraph is unclear. What is $\tau_V$? Are you talking about the **subspace topology** (that is, $\tau_V=\{W\cap V: W\in\tau_X\}$)? If so, the answeris certainly false: $C=V$ is comeager in $V$ but (usually) not comeager in $X$ or $U$ unless $V=X$ or $V=U$ respectively.

Comment: $C$ is comeager in $U$ if and only if $V$ is comeager in $U$. The proof is very easy, you should try to find it yourself.

Comment: @Alex Kruckman - I had a go at proving it myself. The proof had more steps than I thought...if its right!

Answer (score 1):

**To prove "(C is comeager in V ) $\implies$ (C is comeager in U $\iff$ V is comeager in U)"**

**with U, V open sets, with $ $V$ \subseteq $U$ $, as defined in the question.**

Using the identity :

$$U \backslash  C = U \backslash V \; \cup V \; \backslash C \tag{1}$$

Also using :

(i) if C is comeager in open set W then $W \backslash  C$ is meager in W:

(ii) a meager set $V \backslash  C$ is also a meager set in an open set U with $V \subseteq U$

(iii) (meager set A in X) $\cup$ (meager set B in X) = (meager set D in X)

(iv) (meager set A in X) $\cup$ (NON meager set b in X) = (NON meager set d in X)

**For (C is comeager in U $\implies$ V is comeager in U)**

Assume C is comeager in U then from eq(1) & (ii) :

$U \backslash  C$ is meager in U = $U \backslash  V$ $ \cup $ ($V \backslash C$ is meager in U)

As a result of assumption (iii) and (iv)  $U \backslash  V$ can't be NON meager, so $U \backslash  V$ must be meager. This means V must be comeager in U.

**For (V is comeager in U $\implies$ C is comeager in U)**

Assume V is comeager in U then from eq(1) & (ii) :

$U \backslash  C$ = ($U \backslash  V$ is meager in U) $ \cup $ ($V \backslash C$ is meager in U)

As a result of assumption (iii)  $U \backslash  C$ can't be NON meager, so $U \backslash  C$ must be meager. This means C must be comeager in U.

Comment: This is correct, but I would write it more succinctly like this: Suppose $C$ is comeager in $V$ and $V\subseteq U$. If $V$ is comeager in $U$, then $V\setminus C$ is meager and $U\setminus V$ is meager, so $U\setminus C = (U\setminus V)\cup (V\setminus C)$ is a union of two meager sets, hence meager. Thus $C$ is comeager in $U$. Conversely, suppose $C$ is comeager in $U$. Then $U\setminus C$ is meager, and $V\setminus C\subseteq U\setminus C$, so $V\setminus C$ is meager. Thus $C$ is comeager in $V$.

Comment: @Alex Kruckman - nice, thanks. There is a wood beyond the trees !